# How to embed html/jsx markup as text in a static website

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, hugo

I am planing to provide a documentation for a react component library with [hugo](https://gohugo.io) on github pages.

The docs include some javascript that will render live editing examples using [react-live](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-live).

As react-live needs to get passed the inital markup that should be displayed in the editor i need a convenient way to include html markup as well as jsx markup into my static website so that it can be read by my js code to initialize the react components with it.

So the initial markup can be something like:

```
<div>
  <p>Some random html markup.</p>
</div>
```

or

```
<MyComponent>
    <MyOtherComponent color={'papayawhip'} />
</MyComponent>
```

What is the best way to render them into the static site as text so that they will be ignored by the browser.

I already use the approach to put them into `<script>` tags with `type="text/html"` and query the script tags `innerHTML` from my js.

```
<script type="text/html" data-name="live-example-code">
  <MyComponent />
</script>
```

and in my js:

```
const examples = document.querySelectorAll('script[data-name="react-example-code"]');

examples.forEach(example => {
  const code = example.innerHTML.trim();
  // do something with the code string
});
```

Does anybody know better/more convenient ways to do this? Is there any caveat of doing it like this?

Comment: Is escaping not an option? https://gohugo.io/functions/htmlescape/

Comment: @AndrewMyers That would probably work too. Thanks for the tip. That would also enable me to show the code in a placeholder.